# Weak convergence of Hilbert Schmidt operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, weak-convergence

Let $\{T_i\}$ be a sequence of positive operators in $B_2(H)$ converging to $T$ with respect to the weak topology on $B_2(H)$ (space of Hilbert Schmidt operators on $H$). Does $\{T_ix\}$ converges to $Tx$  in norm (or weakly) for each $x\in H$?

I know that $T$ must be positive since positive operators form a convex set and convex weakly closed sets are norm closed.

Answer (score -1):

Fix $x,y\in H$. Then the functional $T\mapsto \langle Tx,y\rangle$ is continuous.
Then the weak convergence $T_i\rightharpoonup T$ implies
$$
\langle T_i x,y\rangle \to \langle Tx,y\rangle \quad \forall x,y\in H,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
T_ix \rightharpoonup Tx \quad \forall x\in H.
$$

Comment: Here $T_i$ is converging to $T$ in weak topology on $B_2(H)$ , not the weak topology on $B(H)$

Comment: does weak convergence in $B_2(H)$ implies weak convergence in $B(H)$?

Comment: misread the question. What is weak topology on $B_2(H)$ then?

Comment: $B_2(H)$ is a Hilbert space. Weak topology is the topology generated by linear functionals on $B_2(H)$

Answer (score -1):

The injection $B_2(H) \rightarrow B(H)$ is linear continuous between Hilbert spaces, so it maps weakly convergent sequences to weakly convergent sequences. In other words, $T_i$ converges weakly.

Comment: $T_i$ converges in norm to $T$?

Comment: No, I made a stupid mistake. Take for instance $\ell^2$, and $T_i$ projection onto $i$-th coordinate.

Comment: Why the downvote?